# Ошибка с динамическим массивом char

Tags: c++, массивы, char

Доброго времени суток, возникла следующая проблема:
Нужно возвести в степень(n>30) число x. c++ я только начал изучать, не будьте слишком строги, но критика приветствуется.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int PowByValue(int x, int n)
{
int rez = 1;
char* rezchar = new char[];
if (n > 30)
{
    int size = sizeof(rezchar) / sizeof((char));
    rezchar[size] = { 1, 0, 7, 3, 7, 4, 1, 8, 2, 4 };
    for (int j = 0; j <= sizeof(rezchar) / sizeof((char)); j++)
    {
        rez++; //функция не  до конца написано, здесь предполагается, что 
                                                                      каждый 
     элемент
    }          //массива будет умножаться на x,и если больше 10, то след элемент +1
    return rez;
}
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    rez *= x;
return rez;
}
void PowByReference(int &x, int n)
{
int rez = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    rez *= x;
x = rez;
}
int main()
{
int x = 2; int n = 30;
cout << PowByValue(x, n) << endl;
PowByReference(x, n);
cout << x;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: В чем проблема то, хотя бы сказали. То что происходит в функции `PowByValue` в условии  `if (n > 30)`, для меня загадка

Comment: ф-ия возводит число x в степень n. но т.к. в int есть ограничение, то я подумал, что будет идеальный вариантом сделать проверку степени: если больше 30, то вовзодит число в 30 степень, потом переносит в массив char и потом продолжить возведение по элементам.

Comment: какой еще динамический массив char? std::string используйте.

Comment: `new char[]` - что под этим подразумевалось?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не хочу тебя разочаровывать, но...

ты выводишь значение в int, которое может находиться в диапазоне -2^31...2^31, т.е. в 30 степень ты можешь возвести только число 2.

вторая ошибка - в функции ты выделяешь память и используешь массив `rezchar`, но не очищаешь потом память, да и снаружи `rezchar` нигде никак не используется (функция возвращает int)

Если ты хочешь использовать операции с БОЛЬШИМИ числами, то это делается так:

1) вместо int (2^32) используется массив unsigned int[size], который будет описывать большие числа (2^(size*32))

2) для этих БОЛЬШИХ чисел пишешь функции сложения, вычитания, умножения, деления (если не ограничиваться размером числа, то умножение скорее всего будет приводить к созданию нового числа/нового массива большего размера max_size3 = max_size1 * max_size2)

и вот после этого можно реализовать уже и функцию степени - можно топорно как многократное умножение, а можно пооптимальнее

Answer (score 0):

вместо sizeof(rezchar)/sizeof(char)  я бы вызвал strlen(rezchar),  и вообше 
   много лишнего и ошибок - лучше писать снова и использовать std::string  функцию 
   to_string, а лучше std::bitset, или std::valarray,

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    double x= 2;
    double n = 20;
    double res = pow(x,n);
    printf("%f^%f=%f\n",x,n,res);
    return 0;
}
```

?